# Compartilhar texto no Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Estou tentando compartilhar o texto da minha web para o Facebook, estou utilizando o [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com) para criar os botões das redes sociais. Ele me proporciona isto:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1" addthis:url="http://www.planow.com.br/jrgrill/dicas.php?id='.$id.'" style="width:29px"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"style="width:29px"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"style="width:29px"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5329d2273cb2c738"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Estou tentando passar o conteúdo por parâmetros, só que não consigo. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Tenta usar a ferramenta Network do navegador e ver como está a requisição do aqruivo `s7.addthis.com/js***`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que possas passar parâmetros ou até definir um URL especifico, tens três formas de o fazer:

- Indicar o parâmetro para o *addThis* na *wrapper*:

  ```
  <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"
       addthis:url="http://www.planow.com.br/jrgrill/dicas.php?id=1">
      <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  ```

  <sup>Tinhas adicionado o parâmetro ao link, mas deve ser na `div` que contém os links.</sup>
- Na configuração, indicas o URL pretendido:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_config = {
      url: "http://www.planow.com.br/jrgrill/dicas.php?id=1"
    };
  </script>
  ```
- Utilizas o `setAttribute()` para definir o atributo `addthis:url` com o URL que pretendes utilizar:

  ```
  <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" id="minhaWrapper">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var addThisWrapper = document.getElementById("minhaWrapper");
    var meuURL = "http://www.planow.com.br/jrgrill/dicas.php?id=1";
    addThisWrapper.setAttribute("addthis:url", meuURL);
  </script>
  ```

Qualquer um desses métodos pode ser utilizado para indicar ao *addThis* qual o URL e respectivos parâmetros que pretendemos utilizar.

---

Link para a documentação do addThis para [Setting the URL to Share](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/125634-setting-the-url-to-share#.UyobGXivjz8) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

Answer (score -1):

Uma alternativa é o plugin para citações que permite as pessoas selecionarem textos na sua página e os anexarem a seus compartilhamentos, para contar uma história mais interessante. Para usar esse plugin não é necessário implementar o login do Facebook ou solicitar outras permissões através da revisão do aplicativo.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/quote#try

[image: Quote Plugin]